# How do I run a folder as a slideshow in CLI in Windows?

Tags: windows, image, command-prompt

I have tried googling it and searching through the help command, but I can't figure out how to make a slideshow out of command prompt, such as the [button that is shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlduj.png):

[image]

Can anybody help?

Comment: That doesn't look like DOS at all. Do you mean the Windows Command line (`cmd`)? If yes, please adapt your tags.